# PHP list while loop

Tags: php, sql, foreach, for-loop, do-while

how do i put list in while loop?

PHP:

```
> $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM
> bs_events LEFT JOIN bs_reservations ON
> bs_reservations.id_event = bs_events.id   
> GROUP BY bs_reservations.id_event 
> ORDER BY bs_events.eventDate ASC LIMIT 20");
```

HTML TABLE:

```
> while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):  
> echo '<tr>';
> echo '<td>' . $r['title'] . '</td>';  
> echo '<td>' . date('d/M/Y', strtotime($r['eventDate'])) . ' / ' . $r['eventTime'] . '</td>';  
> echo '<td>' . $r['location'] . '</td>';  
> echo '<td>' . array($r['username']) .'</td>';  
> echo '<td ></td>';  
> echo '<td ></td>';  
> echo '</tr>';  
> endwhile;
```

the above code will output

```
TITLE        DATE/TIME      LOCATION    USERNAME
=================================================
1       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username
1       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username1 
1       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username2 
2       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username
```

and i want the output

```
TITLE        DATE/TIME      LOCATION    USERNAME
=================================================
1       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username, username1, username2  
2       dd/mm/yyy / hh:mm   location    username
```

or do i need to put foreach on `echo '<td>' . array($r['username']) .'</td>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT title,
       event_date,
       event_time,
       location,
       GROUP_CONCAT(username SEPARATOR ', ') AS username
  FROM bs_events 
  LEFT JOIN bs_reservations
         ON bs_reservations.id_event = bs_events.id   
 GROUP BY bs_reservations.id_event 
          bs_events.title,
          bs_events.event_date,
          bs_events.event_time,
          bs_events.location
 ORDER BY bs_events.eventDate ASC LIMIT 20
```

**EDIT**

Added alias for username

Comment: thanks .. but its showing blank on username. how do i put the username list `$r['username']`?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)